# Convert UTC micros to julia date time

Tags: julia

I have a datetime I'm getting from golang that is in unix microseconds (The number of microseconds since January 1st 1970).

```
1652681499679534
```

I want to get it into a julia datetime.  What is the proper calculation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
julia> unix2datetime(1652681499679534 / 10^6)
2022-05-16T06:11:39.680
```